# Склонение числительных

Tags: склонение, числительные, согласование

Как правильно:

```
1. Готовность объектов от 54 до 81 процента или процентов? 
2. В период с 2014 по 2015 год или годы?
```

Где найти правила по данным примерам?

Comment: @Наталья21061990, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Готовность объектов от 54 до 81 процента. 
2. В период с 2014 по 2015 год.
```

Согласование по последнему слову последнего числительного, потому что предыдущее числительное согласуется с пропущенным существительным: от 54 (процентов) до 81 процента; с 2014 (года) по 2015 год.

Answer (score 0):

Измените название вопроса. Он не о склонении числительных.